# Creating a list of OrderedDicts

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse [this](http://alasky.unistra.fr/MocServer/query?hips_service_url=*&dataproduct_type=!catalog&dataproduct_type=!cube&get=record) comma separated content which lists out some surveys for [HiPS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02291). Here is my code:

```
with open('surveys.txt') as data:
    text = data.read()
    surveys = OrderedDict()
    for survey in text.split('\n'):
        for line in survey.split('\n'):
            # Skip empty or comment lines
            if line == '' or line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            try:
                key, value = [_.strip() for _ in line.split('=')]
                surveys[key] = value
            except ValueError:
                continue
```

The gives me an `OrderedDict` containing the elements of the last survey. This is because the content of `surveys` is over-written after each loop iteration.

I tried to resolve this by creating an `OrderedDict` for each new `survey`, and appending it to a `list`, using this code:

```
with open('surveys.txt') as data:
    text = data.read()
    surveys = []
    for survey in text.split('\n'):
        survey_OD = OrderedDict()
        for line in survey.split('\n'):
            # Skip empty or comment lines
            if line == '' or line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            try:
                key, value = [_.strip() for _ in line.split('=')]
                survey_OD[key] = value
            except ValueError:
                continue
        surveys.append(survey_OD)
```

But this creates a separate `OrderedDict` for each comma separated value, like this:

```
OrderedDict([('hips_order', '3')]) OrderedDict([('hips_frame', 'galactic')]) OrderedDict([('hips_tile_format', 'jpeg fits')])
```

When, instead I expect something like this:

```
OrderedDict([('hips_order', '3'), ('hips_frame', 'galactic'), ('hips_tile_format', 'jpeg fits')])
```

Comment: I don't understand. How is your desired output a list of dicts? It's one dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's slightly improve your first approach:

- separate surveys by double newline character,
- collect surveys in list.

So we can write

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('surveys.txt') as data:
    text = data.read()
surveys = list()
for raw_survey in text.split('\n\n'):
    survey = OrderedDict()
    # Skip empty lines
    for line in filter(None, raw_survey.split('\n')):
        # Skip comment lines
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        try:
            key, value = [_.strip() for _ in line.split('=')]
            survey[key] = value
        except ValueError:
            continue
    surveys.append(survey)
```

will give us

```
>>>surveys[0]
OrderedDict([('ID', 'CDS/C/MUSE-M42'), ('creator_did', 'ivo://CDS/C/MUSE-M42'),
             ('obs_collection', 'MUSE-M42'),
             ('obs_title', 'MUSE map of the central Orion Nebula (M 42)'), (
             'obs_description',
             'Integral-field spectroscopic dataset of the central part of the Orion Nebula (M 42), observed with the MUSE instrument at the ESO VLT (reduced the data with the public MUSE pipeline) representing a FITS cube with a spatial size of ~5.9\'x4.9\' (corresponding to ~0.76 pc x 0.63 pc) and a contiguous wavelength coverage of 4595...9366 Angstrom, spatially sampled at 0.2", with a sampling of 1.25 Angstrom in dispersion direction.'),
             ('obs_ack', 'Based on data obtained from the ESO/VLT'),
             ('prov_progenitor', 'MUSE Consortium'),
             ('bib_reference', '2015A&A...582A.114W'),
             ('obs_copyright', 'Copyright mention of the original data'),
             ('obs_copyright_url', 'http://muse-vlt.eu/science/m42/'),
             ('hips_release_date', '2015-07-07T00:29Z'),
             ('hips_builder', 'Aladin/HipsGen v9.505'), ('hips_order', '12'),
             ('hips_pixel_cut', '0 7760'), ('hips_tile_format', 'png fits'),
             ('hips_cube_depth', '3818'), ('hips_cube_firstframe', '1909'),
             ('hips_frame', 'equatorial'), ('dataproduct_type', 'image'),
             ('t_min', '56693'), ('t_max', '56704'), ('em_min', '4,595e-7'),
             ('em_max', '9,366e-7'), ('hips_version', '1.31'),
             ('hips_creation_date', '03/07/15 12:00:30'),
             ('hips_creator', 'CDS (P.Fernique)'), ('hips_tile_width', '512'),
             ('hips_status', 'public master clonableOnce'),
             ('hips_pixel_bitpix', '-32'), ('data_pixel_bitpix', '-32'),
             ('hips_hierarchy', 'mean'), ('hips_initial_ra', '83.82094'),
             ('hips_initial_dec', '-5.39542'), ('hips_initial_fov', '0.09811'),
             ('hips_pixel_scale', '2.795E-5'), ('s_pixel_scale', '5.555E-5'),
             ('moc_sky_fraction', '2.980E-7'), ('hips_estsize', '87653'),
             ('data_bunit', '10**(-20)*erg/s/cm**2/Angstrom'),
             ('data_cube_crpix3', '1'), ('data_cube_crval3', '4595'),
             ('data_cube_cdelt3', '1.25'), ('data_cube_bunit3', 'Angstrom'),
             ('client_application', 'AladinDesktop'),
             ('hips_copyright', 'CNRS/Unistra'), ('obs_regime', 'Optical'),
             ('hips_service_url', 'http://alasky.unistra.fr/MUSE/MUSE-M42'), (
             'hips_service_url_1',
             'http://alaskybis.unistra.fr/MUSE/MUSE-M42'),
             ('hips_status_1', 'public mirror clonable'), (
             'hips_service_url_2',
             'https://alaskybis.unistra.fr/MUSE/MUSE-M42'),
             ('hips_status_2', 'public mirror clonable'), ('moc_order', '12'),
             ('obs_initial_ra', '83.82094'), ('obs_initial_dec', '-5.39542'),
             ('obs_initial_fov', '0.014314526715905856'),
             ('TIMESTAMP', '1490387811000')])
```